# What could happen if I don't close response.Body?

Tags: go

In Go, I have some http responses and I sometimes forget to call:

```
resp.Body.Close()
```

What happens in this case? will there be a memory leak? Also is it safe to put in `defer resp.Body.Close()` immediately after getting the response object?

```
client := http.DefaultClient
resp, err := client.Do(req)
defer resp.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

What if there is an error, could `resp` or `resp.Body` be nil?

Comment: Its alright to put defer resp.Body.Close() after the err != nil when return is present because, when the err is not nil, it already comes closed. On the other hand the body needs to closed explicitly when the request succeeds.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

> What happens in this case? will there be a memory leak?

It's a resource leak. The connection won't be re-used, and can remain open in which case the file descriptor won't be freed.

> Also is it safe to put in defer resp.Body.Close() immediately after getting the response object?

No, follow the example provided in the documentation and close it immediately after checking the error.

```
client := http.DefaultClient
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

From the `http.Client` documentation:

> If the returned error is nil, the Response will contain a non-nil Body which the user is expected to close. If the Body is not both read to EOF and closed, the Client's underlying RoundTripper (typically Transport) may not be able to re-use a persistent TCP connection to the server for a subsequent "keep-alive" request.

Comment: According to this [link](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#close_http_resp_body) it is still possible to leak the connection with your code.  There are some instances where the response is non-nil and the error is non-nil.

Comment: @mmcdole: That post is just wrong, and there's no guarantee that it won't panic, since whatever response is returned on an error doesn't have a defined state. If a Body isn't closed on an error, then it's a bug and needs to be reported. You should go by the [official client documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do), which states "On error, any Response can be ignored", rather than a random blog post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had a bug report logged against my go library that referenced that source and I hadn't vetted it.  Interestingly, it looks like there was a [discussion about this very source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/AidX-vUBLI0) on the golang mailing list.  It looks that the line you referenced in the docs was recently added in 1.6.2 -- so I assume that is where the confusion came in for the original blogger who wrote the post.

Comment: @mmcdole, that particular line was added recently to try and make the issue as unambiguous as possible. It has always been documented as shown in the official examples.

Comment: @JimB What about draining body? Like io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, req.Body), in case when body is not read entirely (in case of faulty logic in http handler)? Would that be useful or just waste of CPU cycles? I was thinking of adding this to some middleware, since I do not see downside of doing it, but I am not sure if there is a benefit.

Comment: @del-boy: If you expect that client to make more requests, then you should try to read the body so the connection can be reused. If you don't need the connection, then don't bother reading the body. If you read the body, wrap it with `io.LimitReader`. I usually use a fairly small limit, since it's faster to make a new connection if the request is too big.

Comment: @JimB do we need to close the response as well (aside from fully reading it) to make the connection reusable ?

Comment: So, should I close the body if not nil, even if I got an error or not?!

Comment: @lucaswxp: no. from the docs: **`On error, any Response can be ignored`**

Comment: It's worth pointing out that doing `_, err := client.Do(req)` also results in the file descriptor staying open. So even if one does not care what the response is, it is still necessary to assign it to a variable and close the body.

Comment: For anyone interested, the full documentation is (emphasis added): "On error, any Response can be ignored. A non-nil Response with a non-nil error only occurs when CheckRedirect fails, and _even then_ the returned Response.Body is already closed."

Comment: @nishanths: you've quoted verbatim the exact statement that's in the answer already. If the documentation changes (it hasn't yet), then feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: @JimB yeah, that was dumb; I didn't notice that part of the answer.

Comment: Is there any static checker to detect this kind of *resource* leaks ?

Comment: I still do not understand. `file descriptor won't be freed` - what is that mean? This is about RAM? TCP connection reuse?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich: file descriptors are a finite resource, and you will run out if you don't close them (or run out of ports first if that is your lower limit). Yes, this also prevents the connection from being re-used (which I'll note more explicitly in the answer)

Comment: Will the response.Body auto close if error is timeout of read response body not dial timeout  ?

Comment: ```On error, any Response can be ignored. A non-nil Response with a non-nil error only occurs when CheckRedirect fails, and even then the returned Response.Body is already closed.``` From golang http client document. [link](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do)

Comment: What always bothers me is lack of handling error from Close(). Even linter complains, yet there is no nice solution to check the error from Close(). I was always wondering when could call to Close fail here?

Comment: I've learned that the hard way. I struggled for two days in search of this error.

Comment: so even if we only check for resp.StatusCode, we should also close the body?
hmm

Comment: Why do you need to add a `defer` if it is already happening after the error is checked?

Comment: according to official docs: in case of 'success' (no error) you need to read the body and then close `If the Body is not both read to EOF and closed, the Client's underlying RoundTripper (typically Transport) may not be able to re-use a persistent TCP connection to the server for a subsequent "keep-alive" request.`. in case of failure (error occur) no need to close 'On error, any Response can be ignored.', but I dont see problem in closing - any other views?

Comment: @bfday: there is no other "view" to consider, if there is an error `Body` can be nil and you will get a panic calling `Close`. Simply check the error and handle it as documented.

Answer (score 17):

If `Response.Body` won't be closed with `Close()` method than a resources associated with a fd won't be freed. This is a resource leak.

#### Closing `Response.Body`

From [response source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/response.go):

> It is the caller's responsibility to close Body.

So there is no finalizers bound to the object and it must be closed explicitly.

#### Error handling and deferred cleanups

> On error, any Response can be ignored. A non-nil Response with a non-nil error only occurs when CheckRedirect fails, and even then the returned Response.Body is already closed.

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
    // Handle error if error is non-nil
}
defer resp.Body.Close() // Close body only if response non-nil
```

Comment: You should note that they should return within your error handling condition.  This is going to cause a panic if the user does not return in their error handling.

Answer (score 7):

At first the descriptor never closes, as things mentioned above.

And what's more, golang will cache the connection (using `persistConn` struct to wrap) for reusing it, if `DisableKeepAlives` is false.

In golang after use `client.Do` method, go will run goroutine `readLoop` method as one of the step.

So in golang http `transport.go`, a `pconn(persistConn struct)` won't be put into `idleConn` channel until the req canceled in the `readLoop` method, and also this goroutine(`readLoop` method) will be blocked until the req canceled.

[Here is the code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.8/src/net/http/transport.go#L1599) showing it.

If you want to know more, you need to see the `readLoop` method.

Answer (score 1):

See https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go
"When err is nil, resp always contains a non-nil resp.Body."

but they do not say when err != nil, resp always is nil. They go on to say:
"If resp.Body is not closed, the Client's underlying RoundTripper  (typically Transport) may not be able to re-use a persistent TCP connection to the server for a subsequent "keep-alive" request."

So I have typically solved the issue like this:

```
client := http.DefaultClient
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if resp != nil {
   defer resp.Body.Close()
}
if err != nil {
    return nil, err 
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, and there's no guarantee that resp.Body is nit nil when there's an error.

Comment: Thanks @JimB.  The wording in the docs is "On error, any Response can be ignored."  It would be more accurate to say "On error, the response Body is always closed."

Comment: No, because there usually isn't a response body to be closed. If you continue reading that paragraph in the docs - "A non-nil Response with a non-nil error only occurs when CheckRedirect fails, and even then the returned Response.Body is already closed."

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put subsequest requests into a new context, that way you can
use same variable name if you want, without worrying about clobbering any
existing variable, and still closing everything:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   b := new(bytes.Buffer)
   // request one
   r, e := http.Get("http://speedtest.atl.hivelocity.net")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   b.ReadFrom(r.Body)
   // request two
   {
      r, e := http.Get("http://speedtest.lax.hivelocity.net")
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      defer r.Body.Close()
      b.ReadFrom(r.Body)
   }
   // print
   print(b.String())
}
```