# Close response body multiple times after multiple requests in golang

Tags: rest, http, go, request, response

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238518/what-could-happen-if-i-dont-close-response-body-in-golang), it is pointed out that response.Body should be closed to avoid resource leak. It is also shown in the overview examples in [http package godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Overview).

In my test code, I send multiple requests to try an API with

`resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)`

multiple times in the same function. Is this a bad practice? In this case, do I write `defer resp.Body.Close()` after each of them, or just once?

```
url := server.URL + "/ticket/add"                                       
reader = strings.NewReader(`{"id": "test1", "detail": "test1"}`)        
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, reader)                        
assert.Nil(t, err)               

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)                                 
assert.Nil(t, err)                                                      

defer resp.Body.Close()                                                 

assert.Equal(t, http.StatusCreated, resp.StatusCode)                    
// add a ticket with same id                                            
reader = strings.NewReader(`{"id": "test1"}`)                           
req, err = http.NewRequest("POST", url, reader)                         
assert.Nil(t, err)                                                      

resp, err = http.DefaultClient.Do(req)                                  
assert.Nil(t, err)                                                      
assert.Equal(t, http.StatusInternalServerError, resp.StatusCode)
```

A related question, on the server side, i.e., inside the `func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`, is it necessary to close the request body as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to close both responses. Deferring one call to `resp.Body.Close` does not somehow effect the other. The `*http.Response` is different in each case, and they both can be deferred.

On the server side, you do not need to close the `Request.Body` -- from the [`http.Request` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request):

```
// The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
// Handler does not need to.
```

Comment: Your quotation seems wrong, it is about `Request.Body` but @nos is closing `Response.Body` which in opposite to `Request.Body` should be closed by caller.

Comment: @I159: The last paragraph in the post is specifically asking about the `http.Request` "on the server side".

Comment: I'm sorry. I found it out.

Answer (score 0):

#### Bad practice

If you did not reuse `resp` variable, it would be obvious that you are dealing with different response instances each of which must be closed.

> Do sends an HTTP request and **returns an HTTP response** (instance)...

So, the bad practice is not to do several requests but to reuse the same variable for several responses. It causes code unobviousness. And produces unreachable objects which never be finalized.

#### Deferred execution

> A defer statement pushes a function call onto a list. The list of saved calls is executed after the surrounding function returns.

If you have scheduled single or several `defer`red executions with reference to the same variable only the last assigned to the variable object's method will be executed (several times for several `defer`s).

[Playground with an example](https://play.golang.org/p/GRgWMhZ9Gv)

#### Closing `Response.Body`

From [`Response` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response):

> It is the caller's responsibility to
>   close Body.

So, typically you must close each `Response.Body`.

#### Garbage collecting and finalization *(edit)*

Garbage collector invokes bind to collecting objects finalizers to close files, connections and to do other cleanup actions. And there is no finalizers bind to `Body` object by default.

#### Your improved snippet:

```
// ...a lot of code
resp_one, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)                                 
 // BTW, `assert.Nil` just returns whether the assertion was successful (bool) not terminates a test.
if assert.Nil(t, err) == true {
    defer resp_one.Body.Close()                                                 
}

// ...a lot of code
resp_two, err = http.DefaultClient.Do(req)                                  
if assert.Nil(t, err) == true {
    defer resp_two.Body.Close()
}
```